# jquery css get child from a div

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-selectors

I have a div which contains :

```
 <div class="ms-core-deltaSuiteLinks" id="DeltaSuiteLinks">
    <div id="suiteLinksBox">
        <ul class="ms-core-suiteLinkList">
            <li class="ms-core-suiteLink">
                <a class="ms-core-suiteLink-a" id="ctl00_ctl56_ctl03_ShellNewsfeed" href="http://my.nbsdev.co.uk:80/default.aspx"> <span>Newsfeed</span>
                </a>
            </li>
            <li class="ms-core-suiteLink">
                <a class="ms-core-suiteLink-a" id="ctl00_ctl56_ctl03_ShellDocuments" href="http://my.nbsdev.co.uk/personal/dah/Documents/Forms/All.aspx"> <span>OneDrive</span>
                </a>
            </li>
            <li class="ms-core-suiteLink">
                <a class="ms-core-suiteLink-a" id="ctl00_ctl56_ctl03_ShellSites" href="http://my.nbsdev.co.uk/personal/dah/Social/Sites.aspx"> <span>Sites<span class="ms-suitenav-caratBox" id="Suite_ActiveLinkIndicator_Clip">
    <img class="ms-suitenav-caratIcon" id="Suite_ActiveLinkIndicator" src="/_layouts/15/images/spcommon.png?rev=23">
    </span></span>
                </a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

I want to get from this the li elements and then only select the 1st and second li elements and hide them

I've had a go myself with `$('#DeltaSuiteLinks').children('li:first').css('visibility' , 'hidden');` but this doesn't work. Where am i going wrong?

Comment: There are no `li` children of `#DeltaSuiteLinks`. This is evident more easily if you indent your code properly.

Comment: Is there any reason you are doing this with jQuery? It can be done easily with css.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in comments, [children()](http://api.jquery.com/children/) only selects direct childs.

You can use [find()](http://api.jquery.com/find/) instead for selecting all matching descendants and target the first and second `<li>` alone using the [:lt()](http://api.jquery.com/lt-selector/) selector

```
$('#DeltaSuiteLinks').find('li:lt(2)').css('visibility' , 'hidden');
```

Answer (score 1):

`li` is not immediate child of `DeltaSuiteLinks`. Use [`.find()`](http://api.jquery.com/find/) instead of [`.children()`](http://api.jquery.com/children/)

Use

```
$('#DeltaSuiteLinks').find('li:first').css('visibility' , 'hidden');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in CSS alone:

```
ul li:nth-child(-n+2){
    display: none;
}
```

[**Example fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/RoryMcCrossan/8xs7mmp3/)

The caveat of this being the lack of support in IE8 and lower.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution would be :

```
var li = $('#DeltaSuiteLinks').find('li');
li.eq(1).hide();
li.eq(2).hide();
```